# Adding values to function as an object

Tags: javascript, function, object

In JavaScript functions are objects, and as Mr. Crockford writes the two notations below are equivalent:

```
function funct1(){};

var funct = function funct1(){};
```

So when I treat an individual function (not the global object) as a variable that is an object, it works, and my example is illustrated below:

```
function testFunction(){
    var variable = "value"; 
}
testFunction.value1 = "value1";

function testFunction2(){
    var variable = "value2";    
}

alert(testFunction.value1); //returns "value1"

setTimeout(function(){
    alert("setTimeout 5001: " + testFunction.value1); //returns "value1"
    alert("setTimeout 5001 function2: " + testFunction2.value1); //returns "undefined"
},5001);
```

I used a `setTimeout` to ensure the function execution is finished (maybe the time set is not long enough for a 'real' test?).

This looks like an interesting way to store values outside of function execution (as in once a function has terminated and a value that it calculated is intended to be retrieved). Would this be correct? Is it an established coding practice?

One issue I see is there is potential for memory leaks, as once large amounts of data start to get stored and forgotten about these will hang around and cause the script to be sluggish. Is this true? Is there not the same problem with object variables (as in variables with `key:value` pairs)?

I have not seen this used before.

Comment: a) use `var funct = function(){…}`, "function" is not a valid identifier b) Did you confuse *variables* (which are local-scoped) and *properties* (of objects)?

Comment: What is the example with `testFunction2` intended to demonstrate? Notice that the `setTimeout` is unnecessary, your example will be executed synchronously and you don't need to "wait" for anything.

Comment: What would be the point? And what's the timeout for again?

Comment: @Bergi - Good call, I made the edit. Yes I think I might have confused them. testFucntion2 is there to show that no global item has been changed or added to, so the key:value pair added to testFucntion does not apply to testFunction2

Comment: @Newton - timeout is there to allow some time to pass to show that the key:value pair can be retrieved at a much later time.

Comment: @Bergi - if I used these functions as objects to store key:value pairs, will they be collected as garbage at all (during garbage collection)?

Comment: @user1360809 Object are objects and subject to garbage collection like any other. Again: what's the *point*?

Comment: @Newton - don't know, I was messing around, I could use functions in this manner to store values, so that will keep my overhead of how many variables I use down for one...

Comment: Could be an interesting way to organise my code too - so I assign computed values to the functions that compute them and retrieve them when required. Apparently local variables are the fastest and most efficient way to store data (in objects too and not arrays) - are properties of objects not as fast?

Comment: To me it seems that if had used "testFunction.prototype.value1" then I would have created a value that would be shared by any new testFunction object that would be created, but by removing the ".prototype" I am creating a property that is specific only to the testFunction object.

Answer (score 0):

> I used a setTimeout to ensure the function execution is finished (maybe the time set is not long enough for a 'real' test?).

This is unnecessary. Your example code will be executed synchronously and you don't need to "wait" for anything.

> This looks like an interesting way to store values outside of function execution. Is it an established coding practice?

Yes. This is often done for static values that are related to the function, which should be publicly accessible and not pollute the scope. Very common on constructors or "invokable modules".

> as in once a function has terminated and a value that it calculated is intended to be retrieved. Would this be correct?

No. The value that a function has calculated should be `return`ed. Storing it in a static place is a very bad idea, as multiple invocations of the function might interfere with each other.

> One issue I see is there is potential for memory leaks, as once large amounts of data start to get stored and forgotten about these will hang around and cause the script to be sluggish. Is this true?

Yes. But you store it on non-collected properties only if you want it not to be forgotten. You simply wouldn't do this with large data.

> Is there not the same problem with object variables (as in variables with key:value pairs)?

Those are called *properties*, but yes. The only difference is that function objects usually live longer than plain objects (due to their usage, they're not handled differently by GC)